# "Decoded" Fashion ?

Tags: traducción

There is a computer programming event next week, "[Decoded Fashion](http://hack.decodedfashion.com/)".  I had write (in Spanish) that I was going to this event.

I found two translations on Google translate: *descodificar*  *descifrar*.

My impression is both are correct, but what are the differences in meaning?

Comment: "descodificar" is correct, but I usually hear it without "s": "decodificar", which is also right

Answer (score 1):

'Descodificar' means 'decode', 'descifrar' means 'decipher'. The same differences, if any, that apply to English apply to Spanish.
As this in an event name, I don't think you should translate it, but if you have to, the proper translation would be 'Moda Descodificada' (that, by the way, doesn't sounds very cool in Spanish).